# Get different results with different sampling order in Gibbs sampling: what could be wrong?

Tags: bayesian, gibbs, identifiability, spatio-temporal

In sampling a complex spatio-temporal model by Gibbs sampling, I found if I change the order of sampling (for example, to sample $P(\theta_1,\theta_2|D)$, in one try, I sample $\theta_1\sim P(\theta_1|D,\theta_2)$ first, and in another try I sample $\theta_2\sim P(\theta_2|D,\theta_1)$ first.), I will get quite different results. My question is what could be possibly wrong? My candidate answers are,

1. The code contains bugs.
2. The model has a low identifiability.
3. I have not sampled long enough.

Please share your opinion and experience, thanks!

Comment: The results are different due to Monte Carlo variability but you should eventually see the same outcome, e.g., the same marginals for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. If not, there is a bug in your code OR the Gibbs sampler is not irreducible and you see two versions of the stationary distributions (a rare event).

Comment: @Xi'an, Thanks, finally, I figure out it is because I have not sampled enough. The posterior should be the same.